# how to display error message without alert using javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

how to display the error message without alert using javascript below shown my code

function validateForm() {

```
            if (document.getElementById('email').value.trim()=="")
            {
                alert("Please enter your Email");
                document.getElementById('email').focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (document.getElementById('password').value.trim()=="")
            {
                alert("Please enter your Password");
                document.getElementById('password').focus();
                return false;
            }

            }
    </script>
```

my form model code shown in below how to display the error message below the text field

```
 <form  id="register-form" onsubmit ="return validateForm()" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index.php/Login_cntrl/login" method="POST" >

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label class="view-label">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="email" class="input-control" value=""/>

                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="" />



                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-forgot" >Forgot ?</a>  



                    </div>


                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="ulogin" id="ulogin" value="ulogin" >Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-signup">NEW User? Sign up</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

according to you modify my code but still it is not working

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
    if (document.myform.email.value == "") {
    document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML="Please enter a username"; return false;
    }}
    </script>
```

Comment: it depends on the requirement, what is the requirement

Comment: HTML

<form name ="myform" onsubmit="return validation();"> 
JS

if (document.myform.username.value == "") {
     document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML="*Please enter a username*";
     return false;
}

Comment: according to you modify my code but still it is not working

Comment: @Prasad, you have to create a div with ID errors for it to work...
So make (for each input) a label or something to display custom errors for each validated field.

Comment: Please format/indent your code properly. Anyway, what does this have to do with bootstrap modal? Do you want to use that? In that case, just read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using bootstrap; you can use a simple alert message like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="Please enter a username";
```

Replace everywhere you are calling `alert` with javascript code above.

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

Comment: i tried your code but not working in bootstrap modal

Answer (score 1):

I'll do this using error div onto form...

```
    <form  id="register-form" onsubmit ="return validateForm()" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index.php/Login_cntrl/login" method="POST" >

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label class="view-label">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="email" class="input-control" value=""/>

                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="" />



                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-forgot" >Forgot ?</a>  



                    </div>


                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="ulogin" id="ulogin" value="ulogin" >Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-signup">NEW User? Sign up</a>
                    </div>
<div id='errorDiv' class='col-xs-12 pull-right'> </div>
                </form>
```

/// JS ///

```
function validateForm() {

        if (document.getElementById('email').value.trim()=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML = "Please enter your Email";
            document.getElementById('email').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('password').value.trim()=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML = "Please enter your Password";
            document.getElementById('password').focus();
            return false;
        }

        }
</script>
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is full markup: using error option that comes with bootstrap;

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form  id="register-form" onsubmit ="return validateForm()" method="POST" >

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label class="view-label">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="email" class="input-control" value=""/>

                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="" />



                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-forgot" >Forgot ?</a>



                    </div>


                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="ulogin" id="ulogin" value="ulogin" >Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-signup">NEW User? Sign up</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
                </form>



            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateForm() {

        if (document.getElementById('email').value.trim()=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please enter your Email";
            document.getElementById('email').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('password').value.trim()=="")
        {
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please enter your Password";
            document.getElementById('password').focus();
            return false;
        }

    }

</script>
```